# Angularjs dynamically select options on page load

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, dropdown, pageload

I have this app that users can select a list of faults from drop downs drilling down three levels, the issue I am having is when they are opening the item to edit, the first drop down populates on page load and has the selected item from the saved data, the second populates the options but does not select the any items, and the third the same.
**controller:**

```
.controller("Ctrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    var urlString = systems.systems + "/getIssueCodes/" + Id.Id;
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: urlString,
        dataType: "json"
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        var data = response;
        if (data.data.name1 !== "") {
            $scope.Fault = data.data.name1;
            f1 = data.data.id1;

            $scope.faultChangedLoad(f1, (data.data.id2 === null ? "" : data.data.id2));

            $scope.Fault1 = data.data.name2;
        }
        if (data.data.name2 !== "") {
            f2 = data.data.id2;
            $scope.fault1ChangedLoad(f2, (data.data.name3 === null ? "" : data.data.name3));
        }
        if (data.data.name3 !== null) {

            f3 = data.data.id3;
        }

        $scope.Desc = data.data.desc;

    });

    $scope.faultChangedLoad = function (Fault, selected) {

    var urlStr = systems.systems + "/faultCodes/" + Fault;
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: urlStr,
        dataType: "json"
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.fault1Codes = [];
        if (response.data.length > 0) {
            var ms4 = angular.element(document.querySelector('#Main-select4'));
            ms4.removeClass("no-show");
            ms4.addClass("item item-select");
            var ms6 = angular.element(document.querySelector('#Main-select6'));
            if (ms6.hasClass("item")) {
                ms6.removeClass("item item-select");
                ms6.addClass("no-show");
            }
        }
        else {
            var ms41 = angular.element(document.querySelector('#Main-select4'));
            if (ms41.hasClass("item")) {
                ms41.removeClass("item item-select");
                ms41.addClass("no-show");
            }
            var ms61 = angular.element(document.querySelector('#Main-select6'));
            if (ms61.hasClass("item")) {
                ms61.removeClass("item item-select");
                ms61.addClass("no-show");
            }
        }

        $scope.fault1Codes = response.data;

        $scope.Fault1 = selected;
        });
    }
    $scope.fault1ChangedLoad = function (Fault, selected) {

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: systems.systems + "/faultCodes/" + Fault,
        dataType: "json"
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.fault2Codes = [];
        if (response.data.length > 0) {
            var ms6 = angular.element(document.querySelector('#Main-select6'));
            ms6.removeClass("no-show");
            ms6.addClass("item item-select");
        }
        else {
            var ms61 = angular.element(document.querySelector('#Main-select6'));
            if (ms61.hasClass("item")) {
                ms61.removeClass("item item-select");
                ms61.addClass("no-show");
            }
        }
        $scope.fault2Codes = response.data;
        $scope.Fault2 = selected;
    });

    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<label class="item item-select" id="Main-select5">
    <span class="input-label">Issue Code:</span>
    <select ng-model="Fault" ng-change="faultChanged(Fault)">
        <option ng-repeat="faultCode in faultCodes" ng-selected="faultCode.text === Fault" value="{{faultCode.value}}">{{faultCode.text}}</option>
    </select>
</label>
<label class="no-show" id="Main-select4">
    <span class="input-label"></span>
    <select ng-model="Fault1" ng-change="fault1Changed(Fault1)">
        <option ng-repeat="fault1Code in fault1Codes" ng-selected="fault1Code.text === Fault1" value="{{fault1Code.value}}">{{fault1Code.text}}</option>
    </select>

</label>
<label class="no-show" id="Main-select6">
    <span class="input-label"></span>
    <select ng-model="Fault2">
        <option ng-repeat="fault2Code in fault2Codes" ng-selected="fault2Code.text === Fault2" value="{{fault2Code.value}}">{{fault2Code.text}}</option>
    </select>
</label>
<label class="item item-input" id="Main-textarea1">
    <span class="input-label">Description:</span><input type="text" placeholder="Enter  Description" ng-model="Desc">
</label>
```

I have looked everywhere for a solution, I have tried ng-options but that did not help.

Any help is appreciated,
Thank you

Comment: You need to clean up your code before submitting to the community.

Comment: Can you create plunker link? this will help to resolve the issue faster

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution and I want to put it here in case someone else has the same issue.
I could not find any help so I went back to the books, after reading several chapters, I saw (not mentioned in requirements) a bit of code that displayed ng-value instead of value and I tried it, it worked and the data is being displayed.

Thank you